# Non-Examples of Functors and Categories

Tags: category-theory, examples-counterexamples, functors

I'm preparing to deliver some lectures on homological algebra and category theory, and have found lots of nice long lists of examples of functors and categories arising in every-day mathematical practice.  I am interested in a similar list, but for non-examples.

I know, for instance, that the center $Z(G)=\{g\in G\,|\, hg=gh \text{ for all } h\in G\}$ of a group/ring/etc. [fails to be a functor](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/158438/why-is-there-no-functor-mathsfgroup-to-mathsfabgroup-sending-groups-to-th), and that [the association of a Cayley graph to a group fails to be a functor from Groups to Graphs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2437922/can-a-cayley-graph-be-represented-as-a-functor-from-the-category-of-groups-to-th).

[There was an earlier thread about this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2814260/nonfunctor-examples), but with the restriction that non-examples must be functions on objects and on morphisms but fail to respect morphism composition.  I felt like the examples in this thread were somewhat artificial as well.  I'm interested in examples where a student may expect there to be a category or functor involved, but there is not.

Comment: Generally, I think there are relatively few natural examples of this. Non-examples of natural transformations are more common.

Answer (score 6):

Given a topological space we can consider its underlying set. This easily extends to a functor $U: \mathbf{Top} \to \mathbf{Set}$, from the category of topological spaces and continuous functions to the category of sets and functions. It simply sends a continuous function to its underlying function of sets. This makes $\mathbf{Top}$ into a concrete category (i.e. a category with a faithful functor into $\mathbf{Set}$).

Now consider $\mathbf{hTop}$, the category of topological spaces and homotopy equivalence classes of continuous functions. Once more we can simply forget the extra structure of a topological space and consider its underlying set. However, now it is impossible to turn this operation into a functor. In general there is no faithful functor $\mathbf{hTop} \to \mathbf{Set}$.

Relevant [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concrete_category#Counter-examples) and [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/concrete+category#characterization) links.

Comment: If you try the obvious thing and use choice to pick a representative $f$ of each homotopy class $[f]$, then there's no reason to believe that the representative picked for the composition of two homotopy classes $[fg]$ is the same set function as $fg$.  Good example!